# CakePHP MySQL Values

Tags: php, html, cakephp

```
echo $this->Form->input('quantity', array('options' => array('1','2','3','4')));
```

I have this code to input the values 1,2,3 or 4 into the quantity field in my database.

If a user selects 1 it inputs 0, 2 inputs 1 etc.

If the code is

```
echo $this->Form->input('quantity');
```

The user can input what they like and guess what...
It works. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're trying to implement a drop-down box. I think you can try this:

```
$options = array('1' => '1', '2' => '2', '3' => '3', '4' => '4');
echo $this->Form->input('quantity', array('options' => $options, 'default' => '1'));
```

this will create a select drop down box.

For detail please [***see here***](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html).

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I had drop down box, but it thought each number was 1 less. Does the '1'=>'1' etc fix it?

Comment: yes. if you put only `options` array then it will `index` those array item like normal array mechanism. But for your custom indexing you need to set `options` as associative array (key => value) pair.

Comment: The difference with the original code, is that CakePHP uses the 'keys' (indexes) of the array as values and the 'values' as visible labels; `array(1,2,3);` is equal to `array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3);` i.e. the *value* of `1` is `0`

Comment: @BlairMurray welcome.. actually we all are learning every moment.